# How to retrieve microseconds or milliseconds from MySQL current time?

Tags: mysql, datetime, milliseconds

I am trying to create my first stored function on MySQL. In this function I want to return the timestamp of the current date and time with 3 microsecond digits like this: `YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZZZ`

I use this number in my database to create unique keys for my records offline so they don't crash when my systems merge databases from different offline servers.

So my first try for that was `SELECT CAST(MICROSECOND(NOW()) AS CHAR(3));`

But it returns 0.

If I try `SELECT CAST(MICROSECOND('2009-12-31 23:59:59.001210') AS CHAR(3));`

It returns 121, as I need.

**So, How to tell MySQL that I want to know the microseconds of the current time?**

---

EDIT:

Consider this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CHAVE (pTable VARCHAR(32)) RETURNS CHAR(20)
BEGIN
    DECLARE vSigla CHAR(3);
    DECLARE vDateTime CHAR(14);
    DECLARE vMilli CHAR(3);
    DECLARE vKey CHAR(20);
    SET vSigla = (SELECT SIGLA FROM TABLELIST WHERE NOME = pTable);
    SET vDateTime = (SELECT CAST(LEFT(UTC_TIMESTAMP()+0, 14) AS CHAR(14)));
    SET vMilli = LPAD(FLOOR(RAND() * 1000), 3, '0');
    SET vKey = CONCAT(vSigla, vDateTime, vMilli);
    RETURN vKey;
END;
```

The result of:

```
INSERT INTO TABLEX (dateID, name) VALUES (CHAVE('TABLEX'), 'EASI');
```

Will be, from CHAVE('TABLEX'):

```
KEY20130320151159666
```

Where 666 will be a random number, **but I wish it was the real milliseconds count of the current time**, so I have no possible duplicated key.

---

If only I could use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM @TableName WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '%_ID' LIMIT 1` and insert that in a non-dynamic SELECT to get the millisecond of the last record of that table...

Comment: This is a bug fixed in MySQL version 5.6.4 what version are you on?

Comment: I use HostGator.com which is using MySQL 5.5.21 as told in http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/what-software-and-program-versions-does-hostgator-offer

Comment: My local MySQL version is 5.1.5 from Zend Server 5 CE

Answer (score 28, accepted):

MySQL 5.6 supports the millisecond precision in the [`sysdate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) function.

try

`select sysdate(6)` will return `2013-04-16 13:47:56.273434`

and

`select sysdate(3)` will return `2013-04-16 13:47:56.273`

Comment: for MySQL 5.6.4 and later, according to the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at what MySQL says(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fractional-seconds.html):

`However, when MySQL stores a value into a column of any temporal data type, it discards any fractional part and does not store it.`

So you need to store it not as a date value, but as a simple floating point value.

Comment: 5.1 may say that. 5.6 says that too - but expands on the point in some important ways, so the crucial question is 'what version is the OP using?'

Comment: I am not looking for storage, but just to retrieve from system current datetime as told in the question. I will save it as a string value YYYYMMDDHHMMSSZZZ

Comment: If your MySQL version is not new enough, it will be unable to get any part smaller 1 second. It's better to use your server-side scripting language to retrieve it and then put in the query.

Comment: So I wont be able to create that stored function :-(

Answer (score 5):

For mysql 5.6

```
round(unix_timestamp() * 1000  + MICROSECOND(sysdate(6)) / 1000)
```

Comment: Works great on 5.6.32 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can

```
mysql> select now(3) as millisecond, now(6) as microsecond, round(1000 * unix_timestamp(now(3))) elapsed_millisecond, round(unix_timestamp() * 1000  + MICROSECOND(now(6)) / 1000) elapsed_microsecond;
+-------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| millisecond             | microsecond                | elapsed_millisecond | elapsed_microsecond |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-12-10 11:49:43.568 | 2019-12-10 11:49:43.568767 |       1575949783568 |       1575949783569 |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my Solution for Millisecond management.

I just use "text" data type as data store, of cause you have to control data validation by yourself.

CREATE TABLE  `time_test` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`start_time` TEXT NULL ,
`stop_time` TEXT NULL ,
`difference` TEXT NULL ,
`ranking` INT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
)

INSERT INTO `time_test` VALUES (NULL, '10:10:10.111111', '10:10:10.456789',NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO `time_test` VALUES (NULL, '10:10:10.111111', '10:10:20.777777',NULL,NULL)
INSERT INTO `time_test` VALUES (NULL, '10:10:10.111111', '10:10:01.999999',NULL,NULL)

[Now you can calculate like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QPAC.jpg) 
Now you can calculate like this 
sorting
SELECT * FROM  `time_test` ORDER BY TIME( stop_time )

Calculate time diff, very good for me.
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(stop_time,start_time) from `time_test`
[Calculate time diff, very good for me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wt4b.jpg)

also can calcuate and store back you can cut some string by yourself.
update  `time_test` set difference = concat(TIMEDIFF(stop_time,start_time), MICROSECOND(TIMEDIFF(stop_time,start_time) ))
[also can calcuate and store back you can cut some string by yourself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxGVg.jpg)

you also doing ranking by this command:
SET @r:=0;
UPDATE `time_test`  SET ranking= (@r:= (@r+1))  ORDER BY `difference` ASC;
[you also doing ranking by this command:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0mub.jpg)