# Now() vs GetDate()

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am migrating my database from sqlserver to mysql
when i come to `getDate()` function in sqlserver the replacement in mysql is `Now()`
but `Now()` not returned the exact result and format that `getDate()` returned.

Is there any solution to tweak the `Now()` result to make as same as `getDate()`

```
getDate() result : 2014-01-07 00:28:46.017

Now() result     : 2014-01-07 10:28:03
```

Comment: Try `SYSDATE()` instead of `NOW()`. btw. Why do you care about string date representation? Do you store the datetime values as strings in your database?

Comment: SYSDATE() returned same result as NOW().My Point is when I use Now() in simple select statement so my front end application not get the same result as it get in sqlserver.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I overcome the problem of microsecond by usage of

```
    sysdate(3) returned '2014-01-07 10:52:07.252'
```

Thanks for every one suggestions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526597/how-to-retrieve-microseconds-or-milliseconds-from-mysql-current-time

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between the two functions is the milliseconds.
>   Try converting
>   the getdate() to exclude milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The **format** is different but the values are the same. You should format the values according to your needs but as for storage, they should be stored in the binary format (e.g. using `DATETIME` data type).