# MySql Query for selecting users according to the Date of Today

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
$user_countday = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users  WHERE (DATE('user_registered') = DATE(NOW())" );
print_r($user_countday);
```

I am using the above Query for selecting all registerd users of today in wordpress but this is not displaying any answer.
For trying many hours, I didn't got any solution.
Where is the problem in my code?

Comment: does your returned any rows in direct dbms?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with WordPress, but an educated guess is that you are using the wrong function to load results. You are using `get_var` while you may need to use [`get_results`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/).

Comment: I finally got the answer , we need to use get_date() for comparing dates in wordpress.
$date = getdate();

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE DAY(user_registered) = $date[mday] AND MONTH(user_registered) = $date[mon] AND YEAR(user_registered) = $date[year]" );
echo "<p>User count for Today is {$user_count}</p>";

Answer (score 0):

1 more parentheses is needed from dbms query should returned row if wordpress is accurate

```
( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users  WHERE DATE(user_registered) = getdate())" )
```

Comment: I finally got the answer , we need to use get_date() for comparing dates in wordpress.
$date = getdate();

$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users WHERE DAY(user_registered) = $date[mday] AND MONTH(user_registered) = $date[mon] AND YEAR(user_registered) = $date[year]" );
echo "<p>User count for Today is {$user_count}</p>";

Comment: getdate() is mssql funtion not mysql so would i change my answer

Comment: your taging was wrong it would be mssql server then all people would have provided you the correct answer

Comment: GETDATE() works with both MySql as well as Ms Sql.
 Check :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964578/now-vs-getdate for more details.