Use Datediff with specific condition value in one table
I have the following table :



IDno
name
date
status




c123
Ryan
10/05/2024
arrival


f738
Tom
10/05/2024
arrival


c123
Ryan
13/05/2024
arrival


f738
Tom
16/05/2024
departure



I want to using Datediff function to count length of the days from the arrival date. So the result would be like this :



IDno
name
date
status
days




c123
Ryan
10/05/2024
arrival
3


f738
Tom
10/05/2024
arrival
6


c123
Ryan
13/05/2024
arrival
6



-first row between arrival date because Ryan depart from other post
-second row between departure date because Tom departure 16/05/2024
-third row between current date
My queries just like this :
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),date) as days FROM mytable WHERE status = 'arrival';
I know it doesn't work. I must add other function in my DATEDIFF(). How to count the days from the specific condition ?

Are you sure you use MySQL and not MSSQL?

Yes I am, I just learn MySQL

see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964578/now-vs-getdate  . The function GETDATE() does not exist in MySQL, you can use NOW()

Please explain "I know it doesn't work"   For an overview of all date and time function see this link...

want to using Datediff function to count length of the days from the arrival date. -  but your desired outcome shows number of days from an arrival date to the next unspecified event and if no departure then to current date.

You can start with a subquery which will  find the date of the next event for a person. More advanced technique would make use row_number() and left join. Try and tell us which is you problem exactly when creating a query.

You can get the days between arrival and departure like this:
SELECT 
  m1.*, 
  DATEDIFF(CASE WHEN m2.date is null THEN NOW() else m2.date END,m1.date) as days,
  CASE WHEN m2.date is not null THEN m2.date END as arrival
FROM mytable m1 
LEFT JOIN mytable m2 on m1.name = m2.name and m2.status = 'departure'
WHERE m1.status = 'arrival';

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/A9Lu4p6v
EDIT:
To also list the difference in days between two arrivals:
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    m1.*, 
    DATEDIFF(LEAD(m1.date) OVER (PARTITION BY m1.name ORDER BY date),m1.date) as days,
    LEAD(m1.date) OVER (PARTITION BY m1.name ORDER BY date) as nextStatus
  FROM mytable m1 
) x
WHERE x.status = 'arrival'
;

output:



IDno
name
date
status
days
nextStatus




c123
Ryan
2024-05-10
arrival
3
2024-05-13


c123
Ryan
2024-05-13
arrival
null
null


f738
Tom
2024-05-10
arrival
6
2024-05-16



see: https://dbfiddle.uk/xGUlCCQa
now only the second line need to calculate until today which can be done using the COALESCE() function:
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    m1.*, 
    DATEDIFF(COALESCE(LEAD(m1.date) OVER (PARTITION BY m1.name ORDER BY date),NOW()),m1.date) as days,
    LEAD(m1.date) OVER (PARTITION BY m1.name ORDER BY date) as nextStatus
  FROM mytable m1 
) x
WHERE x.status = 'arrival'
;

see: https://dbfiddle.uk/EjLrxFKc

There is no departure for ryan in the sample but there are 2 rules for that.

OP wants 3 days for c123 Ryan 2024-05-10 , till next Ryan arrival.

expanded the output.

Wow good work sir. Thank you very much.
