# Array elements and milliseconds

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add milliseconds to the elements start and end within an array. I have tried several things and I was unsuccessful. First, I bring from mysql an array with datetime formats for start and end elements. The first thing that I need to do is convert the `Y-m-d H:i:s` into a string or other variable type as milliseconds are not supported in the datetime format. The second thing which I need to do is to add milliseconds to the elements start and end in the following array.

```
{"success":1,"result":[{"title":"hola","start":"2015-11-26 18:34:00","end":"2015-11-26 19:34:00"},{"title":"quetal","start":"2015-11-26 18:35:00","end":"2015-11-26 19:35:00"}]}"
```

I tried with both array map, array walk, and array column to change the format and add milliseconds to the array elements but frankly the output is not even closer to what I was expecting. I checked all the documentation and there seems to be an absence to solve this problem.
Does anyone know how to achieve what I am looking to do?

**EDIT:** The idea is to know if there is a way to work with arrays, without spliting the array, and achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand but
 - If you just want to use a format with millisecond, can you write a foreach and add :000 when the key is start or end ?
 - If you want ms form mysql, maybe this link may be helpful [How to retrieve microseconds or milliseconds from MySQL current time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526597/how-to-retrieve-microseconds-or-milliseconds-from-mysql-current-time)

Comment: The idea is to know if there is a way to work with arrays, without spliting the array, and achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the question, just iterate over the array and add the text of interest.

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
    if($key=="start" or $key=="end")
        $result[$key] .= ":000";
```

If you want to save data on DB, this not solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Not certain if that is what you need, but here's a way to add milliseconds on a date in your array :

```
$msToAdd = 10;

$jsonArray = '{"success":1,"result":[{"title":"hola","start":"2015-11-26 18:34:00","end":"2015-11-26 19:34:00"},{"title":"quetal","start":"2015-11-26 18:35:00","end":"2015-11-26 19:35:00"}]}';
$array = json_decode($jsonArray,true);

$start = $array['result'][0]['start'];
$start .= '.'.$msToAdd;
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s.u", $start);
$array['result'][0]['start'] =  $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
//OR if you want to keep the datetime object
//$array['result'][0]['start'] = $start;
//The array at this position should now contains 2015-11-26 18:34:00.100000
//
```

Do the same for the end, it should work. PHP 5.3 +